# How do I create a RowDecoder that combines other RowDecoders in Kantan

Tags: scala, csv

Using Kantan in Scala, I want to create a `RowDecoder[Combined]` for a `Combined` case class that has more than 22 fields. I have created `RowDecoder[PartA]`, `RowDecoder[PartB]`, `RowDecoder[PartC]`, and a method `((PartA, PartB, PartC) => Combined`. Does Kantan provide a way to declare the `RowDecoder[Combined]`?
Ideally the decoder handles the input only once (String containing row => Seq[String] with fields). I have created a RowDecoder[Combined] like this:

```
        implicit val rowDecoder: RowDecoder[Combined] = RowDecoder.from { elems =>
          val line   = elems.mkString(",")
          val (a, b, c) = (partA(line), partB(line), partC(line)) // partA/B/C have a `RowDecoder[PartX]` and do a line.readCsvRow()
          (a, b, c) match {
            case (Left(e), _, _)         => Left(TypeError(e.getMessage))
            case (_, Left(e), _)         => Left(TypeError(e.getMessage))
            case (_, _, Left(e))         => Left(TypeError(e.getMessage))
            case (Right(a), Right(b), Right(c)) => Right(Combined.fromParts(a, b, c))
          }
        }
```

But that performs multiple String -> Seq[String] -> seq.mkString -> Seq[String] transformations that can hopefully be prevented.

Comment: Did you see this: https://github.com/nrinaudo/kantan.csv/issues/104 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @MartinHH for pointing me to that issue, I've created the RowDecoder based on the suggestions there:

```
      implicit val partADecoder: RowDecoder[PartA] = RowDecoder.decoder(0, 1, 3)(PartA.apply)
      implicit val partBDecoder: RowDecoder[PartB] = RowDecoder.decoder(2, 4, 5)(PartB.apply)
      implicit val rowDecoder: RowDecoder[Combined] = RowDecoder.from { elems =>
        for {
          a <- partADecoder.decode(elems)
          b <- partBDecoder.decode(elems)
        } yield Combined(b.colA, a.col1, b.colB, a.col2, b.colC, a.col3)
      }

      def combined(in: String): ReadResult[Combined] = in.readCsvRow(rfc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the limitation to 22 fields is imposed by Scala 2, an **alternative solution** (which might be too involved) could be to **use Scala 3**.

Apparently, kantan.csv has not been released for Scala 3, but one could use the Scala 2.13 release in a Scala 3 project.

I implemented a tiny [demo project](https://github.com/MartinHH/kantan-csv-generic-scala3) to show how this could be done.

What it would take is:

1. Have a Scala 3 project and add kantan.csv as `for3Use2_13`-dependency:

   `libraryDependencies += ("com.nrinaudo" %% "kantan.csv" "0.7.0").cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13)`
2. Use the built-in [type class derivation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/contextual/derivation.html) mechanism of Scala 3 to implement derivation of `RowDecoder`-instances for arbitrary case classes.
   See my example implementation [here](https://github.com/MartinHH/kantan-csv-generic-scala3/blob/v0.0.0/src/main/scala/io/github/mahh/kantangeneric/generic.scala).
3. Use the derivation mechanism to derive your decoder. See an example for a case class with 30 fields [here](https://github.com/MartinHH/kantan-csv-generic-scala3/blob/v0.0.0/src/test/scala/io/github/mahh/kantantest/GenericRowDecoderSuite.scala#L24).

**Limitations:**

1. kantan.csv uses Scala 2 macros from [imp](https://github.com/non/imp) in [a few](https://github.com/nrinaudo/kantan.csv/search?q=macro) [places](https://github.com/nrinaudo/kantan.csv/search?q=imp%5B) to summon implicit instances. I suppose one could workaround those and summon implicits in the language's default way. For example: `val hc = HeaderEncoder[String]` won't compile because of that macro, but `val hc = summon[HeaderEncoder[String]]` will do as a workaround.
2. Scala 3 `RowDecoder` derivation for case classes & tuples relies on recursive inlining and that is limited by the compiler - default value is 32 "nested" inlines which allows for case classes up to 30 fields, but that can be increased using the `-Xmax-inlines` parameters.